# Spring Junit Transaction does not rollback after commit

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource, rollback

I have some Spring Services which I want to test. These Services create a connection (pooled `BasicDataSource`) at the beginning and commit after all DAOs ware successfully called.

Now i want to test them via Spring junit, but the "commit" at the end is not rolled back (even with `@Transactional`).

how can this be done (I have read that spring encapsules the methods into one transaction and rolls it back)?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:TestProject-spring-test.xml" })
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    protected BasicDataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbc;


    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testTransactional() throws SQLException{
        jdbc.execute("INSERT INTO test (pk) VALUES (0)");

        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test (pk) VALUES (1)");
        con.commit();
        con.close();
    }

}
```

The `jdbc.execute` is rolled back, but the `Connection` retrieved by datasource is not rolled back.

how can i force a rollback even if I commit a Connection?

Comment: Well of course it won't... You are obtaining a connection yourself outside of the scope of spring. So for the spring managed connection there is nothing to rollback.

Comment: how then can I get a connection by spring and give it back?

Comment: Use the `JdbcTemplate`... What is it you are trying to test?

Comment: Does JdbcTemplate support connection pooling? I often have a method which creates a connection and passes it to some sub methods. at the end the connection is closed. now I want to use Spring and migrate this "old" logic.

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` doesn't care about that, it uses a datasource. When using properly configured transactions it uses a single connection for the whole transaction. Unless you start messing around with obtaining connections yourself outside the transaction like you are doing in your test.

Comment: ok, so the solution would be to replace all statement.executeUpdate with jdbcTemplate.execute(...) and to use TransactionTemplate to bundle transaction? or is @Transactional in the service method better? are there any best practices? If you could awnser that i will accept the answer as the solution

Comment: For migration you could wrap the datasource in a [`TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html). That should make your legacy code work inside an existing Spring Transaction.

Comment: currently I am not even using DataSource. Only Connections, Statements and so on. SO Id suggest to add @Transactional to the methods and use jdbcTemplate? or is TransactionTemplate better?

Comment: Ehrmm... How are you obtaining a connection? A connection comes from a datasource...

Comment: yep, but from an "old fashined": Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); and conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS); in a applicationbean. thats the reason I want to add springs transaction management capabilities

Comment: Well if you are rewriting then rewriting everything to use a `JdbcTemplate` and use either way of tx management, with a preference to `@Transactional` which should actually be on your service layer NOT the dao layer. Or if that code is in a generic class rewrite it to use an injected `DataSource` let that be managed by Spring and wrap it in the earlier mentioned proxy.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @M.Deinum Spring doesn't know anything about your connection (got directly from your datasource) so you cannot expect it to rollback anything. You should use your spring context (and your spring managed DAOs) to execute your tests. [See this example](http://www.mytechtip.com/2013/07/unit-testing-jpa-spring-framework.html).